# I need to sort an array of strings by popularity of the values inside the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings, with some values multiple times like this.

```
const arr = ['banana', 'orange', 'banana', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana']
```

And i'd like to end up with an array of objects with the most popular value first paired with how many of those values are in the array and so on:

```
const newArr = [
   { fruit: 'apple', count: 4 },
   { fruit: 'banana', count: 3 }, 
   { fruit: 'orange', count: 2 } 
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What result did you get from your attempts?

Comment: @Olian04 I really didn't know even where to begin so i couldn't include what i tried sorry :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using reduce function to reduce the fruit list into object with counts should suffice

```js
const arr = ['banana', 'orange', 'banana', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana']

const partialResult = arr.reduce((result, fruit) => {
  if (!result[fruit]) result[fruit] = 1;
  else result[fruit]+=1;
  
  return result;
}, {});

const result = Object.entries(partialResult).map(([fruit, count]) => ({fruit, count})).sort(({count: countA},{count: countB})=> countB-countA);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: forgot the sort step

Answer (score 0):

Using temprary object:

```
const dict = {}
const newArr = []
arr.forEach(v => {
  if (!dict[v]) {
    dict[v] = {fruit: v, count:0}
    newArr.push(dict[v])
  }
  dict[v].count++
})
newArr.sort((o1, o2) => o2.count - o1.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to check if the element has already been included in the `newArr`; if it is just update the count and if it is not push a new object. And finally sort the `newArry`:

```js
const arr = ['banana', 'orange', 'banana', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana']

const newArr = [];

arr.forEach(fruit => {
    let obj = newArr.find(a => a.fruit === fruit);

    if(obj) obj.count++;
    else    newArr.push({fruit: fruit, count: 1});
});

newArr.sort( (a, b) => b.count - a.count);
console.log(newArr);
```